# What are the biggest wins in the Champions League knock-out stages?

Tags: football, trivia, champions-league

Liverpool won 5 - 2 against Roma in the first leg of the [Champions League 2017-2018 season semifinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%9318_UEFA_Champions_League#Semi-finals). What are the biggest single game wins (by goal differences) in the knockout stage of the Champions League?

Comment: You could have a look at the Wikipedia article: [European Cup and UEFA Champions League records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_records_and_statistics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_records_and_statistics&oldid=838351989)). There is a section "Biggest wins". (You might also be interested in the sections "Biggest two leg wins", "Most goals in a match" and "Highest scoring draws".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**7-0: Bayern München vs Basel**, 13/03/2012, 1/16, second leg

**7-0: Bayern München vs Shakhtar Donetsk**, 11/03/2015, 1/16, second leg

Source: [UEFA.com](https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2455225.html)

If you include European Cups as well, then the win with the biggest margin is:

**11-0: Dinamo Bucharest vs Crusaders**, 03/10/1973 first round, second leg

Source: [theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2003/nov/06/theknowledge.sport)